# Finding the boundary of a convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

[G. R. Duan, 1998](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0005109897002173) shows that the set $\mathcal{S}_n$ of real $n \times n$ Hurwitz-stable matrices (defined as those having eigenvalues whose real part are strictly negative) is a simply-connected, convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with vertex at the origin.

My question is this: **Can we find the exact location of the boundary of $\mathcal{S}_n,$** given some specific order of the axes (e.g., the first $n$ axes correspond to the value of the $n$ entries in the first row of a given matrix, the next $n$ axes correspond to the next row, etc.)?

**If it is not possible to give an explicit parameterization of the boundary (or a list of inequalities defining it), is it then possible to determine other geometrical features of it**, like

1. whether or not the cone is a right cone (it has zero eccentricity),
2. if its axis coincides with one of the axes of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ or if it is off to an angle,
3. what its "opening angle" is, etc.?

I apologize if these questions are either trivial or ill-defined. I'm not formally trained in mathematics, so I may have been relying too much on my geometrical intuition when formulating them. I don't believe $\mathcal{S}_n$ is finitely generated, but instead looks something like this (here in the 3D analogue):

[image]

Any ideas and/or references would be of great help!

---

My alternative to finding the exact parameterization of the boundary would be to simulate it for a specific dimension $n$: I'd take a matrix within $\mathcal{S}_n$ and vary the entries (almost) continuously until I hit the boundary (when my matrix is no longer Hurwitz-stable). Doing this a lot of times, I'd get some points that are on the boundary, but I would then have to fit that to some sort of $n^2$-dimensional cone, which I don't know much about, and that seems like a daunting task. Hence this question.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This isn't much, but it can be shown (using the continuous dependence of eigenvalues on matrix entries) that the boundary will consist precisely of those matrices whose eigenvalues have non-positive real part and contain *at least one* purely imaginary (possibly zero) eigenvalue.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, that is true. $\mathcal{S}_n$ should have quite a lot of symmetry because of that, right?

Comment: absolutely.  At the very least, the boundary is invariant under matrix similarities.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Do you mean that any matrix similar to one on the boundary will also be on the boundary? That makes sense. Does this mean that, if given a matrix $A$ on the boundary, any $B=P^{-1}AP$ (where $P$ is any invertible matrix) will also be on the boundary?

Comment: that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: One interesting thought is that we might be able to build the cone out of curves of the form $\exp(-tQ)A \exp(tQ)$ with $t \in \Bbb R$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That sounds quite interesting, please do elaborate (unfortunately, I'm haven't really been exposed much to matrix exponentiation, so I can't see where this idea comes from). Is $A$ a matrix on the boundary and is $Q$ any orthogonal matrix?

Comment: $Q$ is any matrix whatsoever.  The idea is that $\exp(-tQ) = \exp(tQ)^{-1}$; $\exp(tQ)$ will always be invertible.  This is a common trick in the context of Lie Groups.  I don't know if this leads to anything nice though, honestly.

Comment: I see, so this is a nice trick to generate all possible $P$s (if we let $Q$ be any matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$)? Wouldn't we still only be able to build the subset of the boundary that shared eigenvalues with our known $A$?

Comment: Well, it would be a trick to generate a lot of the possible $P$s.  I'm not sure that we would get the entire subset of the boundary that shares a Jordan form with $A$ using just different $Q$s on the one $P$; my hunch is that this won't work, actually.  The way you usually use this is to build a "local coordinate system" on the surface of, in this case, the boundary.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom All right, that's a shame! I'd like to read more about that technique (building a local coordinate system on a surface), do you have any recommendations for introductions? If we *could* hit all elements of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathrm{exp}(-tQ)$ maybe we could simply let $A$ be diagonal with the appropriate eigenvalues (as described by your initial comment) and then expand from these points, and then this would give the entire boundary? I don't know if that makes any sense, this is kind of unfamiliar territory to me.

Comment: well, they would need to be in Jordan form, since not all Hurwitz-stable matrices are diagonalizable.  But yes, that might be a fruitful approach.  For more on that local coordinate system stuff, look into Riemannian geometry.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you, you have been most helpful!